# Konjugierung der Verben wie googeln

Tags: conjugation

Ich habe schon einige neue Verben gesehen, die schwach sind. Ich würde gerne wissen ob
alle neue Verben schwach sind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schwache Verben sind zum einen die "modernste" (sprachhistorisch neueste) Form der Stammformbildung in der deutschen Sprache, zum anderen die, die am ehesten einer Regel folgen (daher auch manchmal "regelmäßige Verben").

Von daher liegt es nahe, dass neue Verben immer dieser Regel folgen, da die "unregelmässigen" Verben ihre Unregelmäßigkeit "historisch" überliefert bekommen haben - Historie entfällt aber bei neuen Verben.

Wenn es keinen Grund gibt, von einer Regel abzuweichen - Und den gibt es hier nicht, folgen solche Verben eben der Stammformbildung schwacher Verben.

Auch bei manchen Verben, die schon lange Zeit Bestandteil der deutschen Sprache sind, bemerkt man ja eine kontinuierliche Wandlung zur Regelmässigkeit (alt: "backen/buk" vs. neu: "backen/backte" - [*Oh: Hat uns hier Kickstarter ein neues Verb beschert??*]).

Und: Ich kenne kein "unregelmäßiges neues Verb"